# How to get input_shape of each layer in a loop?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have the following code trying to do prediction on the cifar10 dataset using the ResNET32 model. However, I am retrieving an error.

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
X_train = X_train.astype('float32') 
X_test = X_test.astype('float32') 
X_train = X_train / 255.0 
X_test = X_test / 255.0
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train) 
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test) 
num_classes = y_test.shape[1]
#Prediction on a single image  
test_image1 =image.load_img('cat.jpg',target_size =(32,32))
test_image =image.img_to_array(test_image1) 
test_image =np.expand_dims(test_image, axis =0) 
def profiler(model, test_input):
    data_input = test_input
    for layer in model.layers:
        im_imput = Input( batch_shape=model.get_layer( layer.name ).get_input_shape_at( 0 ) )#error thrown on this line
        im_out = layer( im_imput )
        new_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=im_imput, outputs=im_out )
        total_time = 0
        for i in range(averaging_steps):
          start = time.time()
          out = new_model.predict(data_input)
          end = time.time() - start
          milliseconds = end * 1000
          total_time += milliseconds
        avg_time = total_time / averaging_steps
        data_input = out
times = profiler(model,test_image)
```

Error trace:

```
---> 29 times = profiler(model,test_image)
8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)
TypeError: Dimension value must be integer or None or have an __index__ method, got value '(None, 32, 32, 16)' with type '<class 'tuple'>'
```

Comment: You should include the full traceback, not a part of it, as errors cannot be interpreted without the complete traceback.

Answer (score 0):

`print(new_model.summary())` will print input shapes as well as other details.

If you need the input shape of every layer, you can use

```py
for layer in model.layers:
    print(layer.output_shape)
    print(layer.input_shape)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I need the input_shape in a variable to be stored in a variable.